# persp add factor group in R

Tags: r, 3d, margins, layoutmargins

Following the margins vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Motivation I would like to know how to plot using `persp` after a logit containing a triple interaction.

Using only `persp` and `effect` only part of the interaction is shown (`drat` and `wt`)

```
x1 <- lm(mpg ~ drat * wt * am, data = mtcars)
head(mtcars)
persp(x1, what = "effect")
```

[image]

However I would like to see the same graph above but at `am=0` and `am=1`. I tried:

```
persp(x1,"drat","wt", at = list(am = 0:1), what = "effect")
```

But the same graph is produced. How to see two graphs at am=0 and am=1? or at least two curves representing am=0 and am=1 in the same cube.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can do it with the `persp.glm()` function in the `margins` package.  You will probably have to do it "by hand".

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$hihp <- as.numeric(mtcars$hp > quantile(mtcars$hp,.5))
x1 <- glm(hihp ~ drat * wt * am + disp + qsec, data = mtcars, family=binomial)
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

drat_s <- with(mtcars, seq(min(drat), max(drat),length=25))
wt_s <- with(mtcars, seq(min(wt), max(wt), length=25))

pred_fun <- function(x,y, am=0){
  tmp <- data.frame(drat = x, wt = y, am=am, 
                    disp = mean(mtcars$disp, na.rm=TRUE), 
                    qsec = mean(mtcars$qsec, na.rm=TRUE))
  predict(x1, newdata=tmp, type="response")
}


p0 <- outer(drat_s, wt_s, pred_fun)
p1 <- outer(drat_s, wt_s, pred_fun, am=1)


persp(drat_s, wt_s, p0, zlim=c(0,1), theta=-80, col=rgb(.75,.75, .75, .75), 
      xlab = "Axle Ratio", 
      ylab="Weight", 
      zlab="Predicted Probability")
par(new=TRUE)
persp(drat_s, wt_s, p1, zlim=c(0,1), theta=-80, col=rgb(1,0,0,.75), xlab="", ylab="", zlab="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

#### Edit: what if you add a factor to the model?

If we turn `cyl` into a factor and add it to the model, we also have to add it to the `tmp` object in the `predfun()` function, however it has to have the same properties that it has in the data, i.e., it has to be a factor (that has a single value) that has the same levels and labels as the one in the data. Here's an example:

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$hihp <- as.numeric(mtcars$hp > quantile(mtcars$hp,.5))
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
x1 <- glm(hihp ~ drat * wt * am + disp + qsec + cyl, data = mtcars, family=binomial)
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

drat_s <- with(mtcars, seq(min(drat), max(drat),length=25))
wt_s <- with(mtcars, seq(min(wt), max(wt), length=25))

pred_fun <- function(x,y, am=0){
  tmp <- data.frame(drat = x, wt = y, am=am, 
                    disp = mean(mtcars$disp, na.rm=TRUE), 
                    qsec = mean(mtcars$qsec, na.rm=TRUE), 
                    cyl = factor(2, levels=1:3, labels=levels(mtcars$cyl)))
  predict(x1, newdata=tmp, type="response")
}


p0 <- outer(drat_s, wt_s, pred_fun)
p1 <- outer(drat_s, wt_s, pred_fun, am=1)


persp(drat_s, wt_s, p0, zlim=c(0,1), theta=-80, col=rgb(.75,.75, .75, .75), 
      xlab = "Axle Ratio", 
      ylab="Weight", 
      zlab="Predicted Probability")
par(new=TRUE)
persp(drat_s, wt_s, p1, zlim=c(0,1), theta=-80, col=rgb(1,0,0,.75), xlab="", ylab="", zlab="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it worked on my dataset. I tried to add other independent variables but got error using the piece of code you wrote. Let's say the model is `x1 <- glm(hihp ~ drat * wt * am + disp + qsec, data = mtcars, family=binomial)` do I only need to add them both to p0 and p1?

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro I updated the answer to use the model in your comment.  The only change is that you have to set the values of the variables you added to the model in the `pred_fun()` function.

Comment: How to deal with factor variables in this solution? For example if `disp` was `factor(disp)` instead? I added 2 factor variables to the glm model above and even adding or not them to `tmp` inside the function `pred_fun` I get error when trying to run `p0` and `p1` as the factor variables are not recognized.

Comment: `disp` is a bad example because it has a different level for nearly every value - it is clearly a numeric variable.  I added an example turning `cyl` into a factor and using that in the model.